# Dynamic Cast Returns null

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

I am facing an issue where dynamic_cast is returning null. I'm trying to downcast from a Card* to GCard*, where GCard is a derived class of Card (which is polymorphic).

Below is the code sample that is failing. I would appreciate if someone could tell me the reason for this failure.

```
class Card
{
public:
   Card(Rank, Suit);
   virtual ~Card();
   void SetSelected(bool selected);

   Suit mSuit;
   Rank mRank;
   bool mSelected;
};

class GCard : public Card
{
public:
   GCard(Rank, Suit);
   virtual ~GCard();

   void LoadTexture();
   void SetDepth(int);

   sf::Sprite mSprite;
   int mDepth;
private:
  sf::Texture mTexture;
};

int main(void)
{
   Card c(Two, clubs);
   Card* pC = &c;

   GCard* pG = dynamic_cast<GCard *>(pC);
   if (!pG)
   {
      cout << "Dynamic cast returned null"; // This line is being executed
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c` is instantiated as `Card`. Why'd you expect something different here?

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic_cast` is returning `nullptr` because your object quite clearly ***is NOT*** a `GCard`. Dynamic casting is not a mystically magical mechanism to transform objects into things they ***are NOT***. All it does is allow you to use an object as the subclass type if it ***already IS*** that type.

The following would behave as you expect:

```
int main(void)
{
   GCard c(Two, clubs); //Note the key change, the object **IS-A** GCard
   Card* pC = &c;

   GCard* pG = dynamic_cast<GCard *>(pC);
   if (!pG)
   {
      cout << "Dynamic cast returned null"; // This line would no longer be executed
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Craig. I totally missed that. I understand that the object should be a GCard to start with.